# How to create an ctrl button hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to create something on my website.

If i push the ctrl button i want him to go to a hyperlink like an page on my website,

I really don't know how to do that...

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the key based events (`keydown`, `keyup`, `keypress`) to interrogate the `ctrlKey` property of the event to find if the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key was pressed. Something like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) 
        window.location.assign('foo.html');
});
```

Comment: Add this code your currnet avtive page, if you include js file then add this code to js file.